# Adding Data to JTable from different Class

Tags: java, swing, jtable

SO I have this Test Client which will run the program and i want this class to populate a JTable in a JPanel class named StartScreenPlayerPanel.
I've tried several methods which failed.

TestClient Class

```
import view.MainFrame;
import view.StartScreenPlayerPanel;

public class TestClientGUI {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleTestClientGUI.class.getName());
    private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    MainFrame mainframe;
    StartScreenPlayerPanel startScreenPlayerPanel;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final GameEngine gameEngine = new GameEngineImpl();

        //GUI - new MainFrame

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    System.out.println(screenSize);
                    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The Class with the JTable - "StartScreenPlayerPanel"

```
public class StartScreenPlayerPanel extends JPanel {
    MainFrame mainframe;

    //private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 

    public StartScreenPlayerPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        model.addColumn("Player"); 
        model.addColumn("Initial Points"); 

        //model.addRow(new Object[]{"v1", "v2"});

        add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }
    public void setModel(String c1, String c2) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{c1, c2});
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public DefaultTableModel getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }

}
```

What I tried So far ;

```
//Add players to GUI
        StartScreenPlayerPanel startScreenPlayerPanel = new StartScreenPlayerPanel();
        startScreenPlayerPanel.setModel("CoinMaster","TheLoser");
        startScreenPlayerPanel.getModel().addRow(new Object[]{"CoinMaster", "TheLoser"});
        startScreenPlayerPanel.getModel().setValueAt("TheLoser", 2, 2);
```

Nothing I tried worked, except doing it in the same class

Thanks For your help.

Edit - Added code for MainFrame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    private StartScreenPlayerPanel startScreenPlayerPanel;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                    System.out.println(screenSize);
                    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainFrame() {

        startScreenPlayerPanel = new StartScreenPlayerPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, (screenSize.width * 2 / 3), (screenSize.height * 2 / 3));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{1200, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{74, 0, 446, 0, 0};
        gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("The Coin Game",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (int)screenSize.width/30));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTitle = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblTitle.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_lblTitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_lblTitle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gbc_lblTitle.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblTitle.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblTitle.gridy = 0;
        contentPane.add(lblTitle, gbc_lblTitle);

        JPanel StartScreenBtnPanel = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridwidth = 0;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel.gridy = 1;
        contentPane.add(StartScreenBtnPanel, gbc_StartScreenBtnPanel);
        StartScreenBtnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JButton btnAddPlayer = new JButton("Add Player");
        btnAddPlayer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        StartScreenBtnPanel.add(btnAddPlayer);

        JButton btnStartGame = new JButton("Start Game");
        btnStartGame.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        StartScreenBtnPanel.add(btnStartGame);


        GridBagConstraints gbc_playerPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_playerPanel.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_playerPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_playerPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_playerPanel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_playerPanel.gridy = 2;
        contentPane.add(startScreenPlayerPanel, gbc_playerPanel);

    }

    public StartScreenPlayerPanel getStartScreenPlayerPanel() {
        return startScreenPlayerPanel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any code that adds a StartScreenPlayerPanel to your MainFrame.

Comment: I didn't Include them would they be helpful?

Comment: Yes.  Furthermore, please show us the exact code you are running.  Does `TestClientGUI` really declare two MainFrame variables (namely, `frame` and `mainframe`)?  Does `TestClientGUI` really declare a `startScreenPlayerPanel` field that it never uses?  I suspect you may be modifying a StartScreenPlayerPanel which is a different instance from the one you added to your MainFrame.

Comment: Hey man, i added the code for MainFrame, thanks

Comment: MainFrame contains its own StartScreenPlayerPanel.  Remove all code outside of the MainFrame class which contains `new StartScreenPlayerPanel()`.  Changing a separate new panel will not affect the one which is actually in your MainFrame.

Comment: Hey,Thanks that really helped, I figured it out